# Add context menu entry to Eclipse synchronize view

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to add a context menu entry (with a sub-menu) in the synchronize view in a custom Eclipse plugin. I have it displaying properly in the Project Explorer, Navigator, and other views, but not the sync view.

Even if I use `<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">`, the context menu is added everywhere *except* the sync view. What is different about the sync view from all others? I'm testing with Eclipse Neon (4.6.3).

**Here's part of my plugin.xml:**

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <!-- this works to add a context menu entry to the Project Explorer view -->
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
        <menu label="My Menu" id="myplugin.menus.projectExplorerMenu">
            <command commandId="myplugin.commands.command1" id="myplugin.menus.command1"></command>
        </menu>
    </menuContribution>

    <!-- this does NOT add a context menu entry to the Synchronize view -->
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.team.sync.views.SynchronizeView?after=additions">
        <menu label="My Menu" id="myplugin.menus.synchronizeMenu">
            <command commandId="myplugin.commands.command1" id="myplugin.menus.command1"></command>
        </menu>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

**Here is the plug-in spy for the Synchronize view:**

[image: Synchronize View Plug-in Selection Spy]

Answer (score 0):

SynchronizeView`is a PageBookView which means it has multiple pages each of which may have a separate menu id. The page you are looking at is`ModelSynchronizePage`.

You can use Menu Spy (F2) to get details of the context menu. Testing here it looks like ModelSynchronizePage doesn't specify an id for its menu.

It looks like the synchronize code still uses the older `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point with `objectContribution` which doesn't need a menu id.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I'm not familiar with the `objectContribution` element. How would I get my menu element in there? Better yet, is there a resource that gives an example of this with the older popupMenus that describes what everything is doing? I can stare at random eclipse plugin.xmls until I'm blue in the face, but I don't know what they are doing.

Comment: The problem with objectContribution is that you need a detailed knowledge of the objects that the view uses - which needs a lot of research.